# Formal proof of: $x>y$ and $b>0$ implies $bx>by$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, axioms, real-numbers

**Property**: If $x,y,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>y$ and $b>0$, then $bx>by$.

What is a formal (low-level) proof of this result?  Or is this property taken as axiomatic?

The motivation for this question comes from an earlier question ([If $a > 1$ then $a^2 > a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666813/91818)) where the accepted answer (in my opinion) amounted to saying it's a special case of the above result.

---

With Asaf Karagila's suggestion, here's a first attempt at achieving a low-level proof:

We will use the [ring axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29), and the following [ordered ring axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring):

> Axiom 1: If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \leq b$, then $a+c \leq b+c$.
>
> Axiom 2: If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $0 \leq a$ and $0 \leq b$, then $0 \leq ab$.

We need the property that $\mathbb{R}$ has no zero divisors; we'll take this as an axiom:

> Axiom 3: If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ab=0$, then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

And we take the definition of $>$ as:

> Definition 1: If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $b \leq a$ and $a \neq b$, then $a>b$.

We will also use the following group lemmas (each of which admit proofs using only the group axioms for $(\mathbb{R},+)$):

> Lemma 1: If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq b$, then $a+c \neq b+c$.
>
> Lemma 2: If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a(-b)=-(ab)$.

Then for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$\small
\begin{align*}
x>y & \iff y \leq x \text{ and } x \neq y & \text{by Definition 1} \\
 & \iff y+(-y) \leq x+(-y) \text{ and } x+(-y) \neq y+(-y) & \text{by Axiom 1; Lemma 1} \\
 & \iff 0 \leq x+(-y) \text{ and } x+(-y) \neq 0 \qquad (*) & \text{additive inverse } \\
 & \iff x+(-y)>0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (**) & \text{by Definition 1 } \\
\end{align*}
$

Hence, for $x,y,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$\small
\begin{align*}
x>y \text{ and } b>0 & \implies 0 \leq x+(-y) \text{ and } x+(-y) \neq 0 \text{ and } b>0 & \text{by } (*) \\
 & \implies 0 \leq x+(-y) \text{ and } x+(-y) \neq 0 \text{ and } 0 \leq b \text{ and } b \neq 0 & \text{by Definition 1} \\
 & \implies 0 \leq b(x+(-y)) \text{ and } x+(-y) \neq 0 \text{ and } b \neq 0 & \text{by Axiom 2} \\
 & \implies 0 \leq b(x+(-y)) \text{ and } b(x+(-y)) \neq 0 & \text{by Axiom 3} \\
 & \implies b(x+(-y))>0 & \text{by Definition 1} \\
 & \implies bx+b(-y)>0 & \text{left distrib.} \\
 & \implies bx+(-(by))>0 & \text{by Lemma 2} \\
 & \implies bx>by & \text{by } (**)
\end{align*}
$
proving the claim.

Comment: If you want to talk about the "low-level proof" you need first to supply the theory from which this proof is to be constructed.

Comment: Well I'm not familiar enough with the topic to distinguish a well-established theory from random-person-on-the-internet's theory.  Would you be able to suggest a starting point please?

Comment: "The theory of Ordered Rings" is a good place to start.

Comment: You can't prove Lemma 2 using just group axioms, because group axioms only allow you to talk about addition, and you involve multiplication.

Comment: Ah, you're right; it's a bug.  This is why I was hoping someone would have access to a canonical answer for me.

Comment: But you *can* prove this from ring axioms.

Answer (score 4):

From $x>y$ you know that $x-y>0$, since $b>0$ you will have $b(x-y)>0$ (the product of two positive numbers is positive). So $bx>by$. I'm not sure if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The basic fact is that product of two positive numbers is positive and $x>y$ is shorthand to $x-y>0$.

Hence
$$
(x>y), ~~\text{and}~~b>0 \Rightarrow b (x-y) > 0 \Rightarrow bx -by >0 \Rightarrow bx > by$$

Answer (score 0):

this is a very interesting question! When it comes to $\mathbb R$, there is basically two options:

1) Define it by an axiom: $\mathbb R$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) of Archimedian totally ordered field satisfying the least upper bound property. With this axiom, the property you want to prove is part of the definition of totally ordered set.

2) Define $\mathbb N$ by the Peano axioms and then build $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ by the usual constructions. So, you have to prove the property for $\mathbb N$ (should work by induction) and then extend it at every step of the construction.